# Handling VBA macros concurrency in a single Excel instance

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, excel-interop, vba

I'm developing a .NET application to do some automation tasks in Excel (run macros, refresh connections, etc). But due to [{this issue}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540576/unexpected-behavior-when-refreshing-internal-data-connections-in-excel) I need to run all tasks in only one instance of Excel.

If an instance of Excel is already open, I use it, else I create a new one. The problem is that Excel is single thread, so I need to handle concurrency when multiple instances of my application are running at the same time. At the momment, I just catch the COM exception "0x800AC472" and retry (with a sleep of X seconds) until the running task has ended. However, it's not a very robust solution, several errors occurs and some deadlock issues appears.

Can I handle Excel concurrency in a robust way?

I have already in my code an implementation of IMessageFilter, but it's not sufficient.

Thanks